# WSO2IS REST API for change Password By user

Tags: rest, soap, wso2-identity-server

there is soap API in WSO2IS, called changePasswordByUser, that users can change their password using (username, current passwprd, New Password).
know because of some considerations I need to use Rest API instead of SOAP API.

**I want to know is there and equivalent rest API of  changePasswordByUser?**

I am using wso2is version 5.8.0

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent REST Service for the changePasswordByUser call in UserAdmin SOAP service.

But if your requirement is to change the users' password and it's not originating from the recovery flow, you should be able to SCIM APIs. Please refer following for SCIM APIs https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#MeEndpoint#patchUserMe

Else you can use the convert soap service to rest service and use it.

Comment: thank you. I think in this API password sent over network in plain text, and it is a deep security hole. how can I convert  soap to rest? using tools like wso API manager?